# Detect color of a pixel without changing color space

Tags: image, image-processing, colors, rgb

We all know that the easiest way to mark as **RED** (0xFFFF0000) both scarlet and dark red passes through HSB/HSV color space.

However I have to process a large image on a small device, hence this operation (convert and compare thresholds) requires too much computational time.

Do you know if it is possible to do the same operation (only compare thresholds in this case) with RGB values ?

And If (as I hope) the answer is yes, I would like to know the "standard" thresholds for the following colours:

- WHITE
- BLACK
- RED
- BLUE
- GREEN

Because these are the only colours that theoretically should be in the images.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which colours are likely to be present in the greatest volume - testing for the most commonly occurring colour first is likely to be fastest. Have a look at an RGB colour cube and you should see that all the colours you seek are at the extreme corners so your testing can be quite fast.

Comment: You are right, but I have spent almost one day on making "trial and error" and it has been very hard to find an accurate measure. There are too many values to test ( 3 upper bounds and 3 lower bounds for each color).

Comment: If you only have those 5 colours in your image, as soon as the Red component is over 127 you can only have red or white. Likewise if the green component is over 127 you can only have green or white...

Comment: I think I have not properly understood. [255,127,0] is orange (suppose red), contrary [0,127,255] is blue and in both cases green is over 127. Can you please explain me better?

Comment: Your question says you don't have orange - you only list black, white, red, blue and green as possible colours.

Comment: @sgramo93 What result would you expect for a yellow=[255,255,0] pixel ?

Comment: Let's suppose I have this image [link](http://www.countryaah.com/images/United_Arab_Emirates_Flag.gif). The image is perfect in the sense that colours are well separated and easy to spot. What if now I take a picture to the image with the phone? There will not be anymore the "perfection" and we will have pixels with different shades of Red,White,Black and Green. Using HSV it is easy to "restore"the original colors, but I do not want to transform RGB to HSV.

Comment: @AldurDisciple I do not expect yellow, but it is possible that some shades of yellow are present in the image ( the ones closer to the white). Do you have an idea on how to create some boundaries for these colors?

Comment: @sgramo93, why do you not want to convert to HSV? it is not computationally expensive operation; probably less than 1ms for a 1MP image. Also, which language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HSV formula or conversion table to get HSV value from RGB and
then use converted value as threshold:

http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm

Edit: Maybe I'm missing again, but I'll give a shot.

Because its RGB colors space, you can use upper/lower boundaries.
So, you need to test each pixel channel against specified casting values:

[Lr, Lg, Lb] <= pixel <= [Ur, Ug, Ub]

For red color, it could be:

[128, 0, 0] <= pixel <= [255, 0, 0]

Additionally, you can add possibility to test if all pixel channels are equal (for some grayscale pixels).
So, some structure to hold upper/lower boundaries should look like:

```
struct test_color_stru
   {
   Byte up[3];
   Byte low[3];
   bool cheq; 
   };
```

You can create an array of this structure that will hold all your desired testing colors.
Some C-like code to test image values should look like:

```
bool match[test_color.count]; 
for (int i = 0; i < img.hegith; i++)
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < img.width; j++)    
        {
        for (int k = 0; k < test_color.count; k++)
            {
            match[k] =  true;
            for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
                {
                match[k] &=  (test_color[k].low[n] <=  img.pixel.ch[n] &&  img.pixel.ch[n] <= test_color[k].up[n]);                                     
                if (test_color.cheq && n > 0)
                   match[k] &= (img.pixel.ch[n] == img.pixel.ch[n-1]; 
                }
            if (match[k])
               cast_color() // or something you want to do with image pixel     
            }   
        }
    }
```

It will not work for situations where one channel value is free (inside some u/l bound) and other channels value must be equal (again in some u/l bound).

Comment: I do not want to convert into HSV, as I wrote before I want to find thresholds in the RGB space if any. Thanks anyway

Comment: I misunderstood the question...thought your image is in HSV space. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a simple threshold of 50% on each of the RGB axes which will give you one of 8 possible outcomes. Rather than running `if` statements which tend to stall processors, you may find it faster to just do some simple maths and a lookup.

So, basically, we want to determine if the Red is more or less than 128, if the Green is more or less than 128 and if the Blue ss more or less than 128. A shift of 7 places to the right will give us the MSB of each and tell us that. If we take the MSB of the Red, Green and Blue and make them into a 3 bit number we can simply look up the answer in a table.

In concrete terms, calculate:

```
index= ((R>>5)&4) | ((G>>6)&2) | ((B>>7)&1)
```

we now have an 8-bit number with the following bits:

```
0 0 0 0 0 R G B
```

and if you pre-calculate a static table as follows:

```
RGB[0]=Black
RGB[1]=Blue
RGB[2]=Green
RGB[3]=Cyan
RGB[4]=Red
RGB[5]=Magenta
RGB[6]=Yellow
RGB[7]=White
```

Then your answer will be

```
RGB[index]
```